# Entity framework removes all rows instead of one

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, dbcontext

I am stuck on a small problem. I want to remove one row based on an ID. But I keep deleting all my rows instead.

This is my code in my datalayer. You can read the word "eigenaar" as "owner".

```
public void removeEigenaar(int eigenaarID)
    {
        transaction = connection.BeginTransaction();
        try
        {
            using (context = new MyDbContext(connection, false))
            {
                context.Database.Log = (string message) => { Console.WriteLine(message); };
                context.Database.UseTransaction(transaction);
                //----------------------------

                Eigenaar e =
                    (from s in context.Eigenaars
                     where s.ID == eigenaarID
                     select s).First();
                context.Eigenaars.Remove(e);

                //----------------------------
                context.SaveChanges();
            }
            transaction.Commit();
        }
        catch
        {
            transaction.Rollback();
            throw;
        }
    }
```

If I debug the code, i can see that my "e" is filled with one owner. That's what i find so strange.

edit
[sql](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iQn25.png)

My delete query works, it just deletes way to much.

Comment: Side tip: If you expect one result back, use `.Single()` instead of `.First()` to save headaches later

Comment: Also, why do you use `s` as your variable name in the linq statement? Wouldn't `e` make more sense?

Comment: What is the SQL being run here? You're printing it out so it should be trivial to figure out.

Comment: I use mysql if that's what you're asking

Comment: No, what is the actual SQL being executed?

Comment: Is the property `Id` declared as the primary key or is another property a primary key and is shared by all other records with one value?

Comment: What version of ef is this as well?

Comment: EF 6.0, my id is infact my key. But i tested with a string that wasn't my key. And it keeps removing al my rows.

Comment: If you don't provide more information, I will be forced to vote to close this question as not having a [mcve]. Can you at least tell us what the actual SQL code being executed is? I'm talking about something that looks like `DELETE FROM SomeTable.....`

Comment: none, am not using sql code. I just use ef code first

Comment: Yes, but EF will translate that into SQL which you are outputting with the `Console.WriteLine(message)` method.

Comment: oh ok, i will look

Comment: I added it to my question

Comment: Did it delete 4 rows? Hard to tell based on the output. If so, you really should change that .First() to a .Single(). I suspect you have multiple records in the db with the same ID. If that is not expected, a .Single() would have saved you here

Comment: I added single but that didn't solve my problem. And can you even make a mysql tabel with duplicated keys?

Comment: You say "key" but that is ambiguous. Primary keys have to be unique but "keys" do not, in general...

Comment: I am sure there are no duplicate keys. is my problem somting with my context?

Comment: No clue. You need to provide a lot more info I'm guessing. Since it's so open ended, you'll need to narrow down the problem and then ask a new question most likely. This one doesn't seem to be going anywhere

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem.

In my mydbcontext.cs i added:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Eigenaar>().MapToStoredProcedures();
        modelBuilder.Entity<Eigendom>().MapToStoredProcedures();
        modelBuilder.Entity<Eigenschap>().MapToStoredProcedures();
        modelBuilder.Entity<Overeenkomst>().MapToStoredProcedures();
        modelBuilder.Entity<Panden_has_eigenschappen>().MapToStoredProcedures();
    }
```

Removing this code fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding:

```
context.Entry(e).State = EntityState.Modified;
```

before

```
context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: yep, one minute

Comment: FYI, I don't think this is related

Comment: That's very strange. Adding your code makes all my values in my table the same. Nothing gets deleted but all my other rows change in the row i wanted to delete.

Comment: Try context.Entry(e).State = EntityState.Deleted;

Comment: That was already posted as an answer, downvoted and then deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Some Modification of your code:

```
IEnumerable<Eigenaar> e= (from s in context.Eigenaars
                 where s.ID == eigenaarID
                 select s).ToList();    
context.Eigenaars.DeleteAllOnSubmit(e);
context.SubmitChanges();
```

OR

You could do a normal SQL truncate or delete command, using the DataContext.ExecuteCommand method:

```
context.ExecuteCommand("DELETE FROM Entity");
```

Or

```
context.ExecuteCommand("TRUNCATE TABLE Entity");
```